# How to write to different sections of a window using console.log in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm wondering if it's possible to write to different sections/portions of a node.js terminal window when I log output. Kind of like divs with html.

So can I for example split the window to two columns and `console.log` things in one side, and `console.log` things to the other side? (without using a library like tmux).

Answer (score 1):

[Console.table](https://console.spec.whatwg.org/#table) would have been a good bet, but it is not yet implemented.

[Console.printer](https://console.spec.whatwg.org/#printer) shows more promise, but is reliant on the implementation method used to do the formatting. If you scroll down to the example, your best option might be to use something like [this example](https://console.spec.whatwg.org/#nodejs-printer) to define your own formatter which writes to either stdout or stderr.